# Cocos 2d-x 3.0 - How does scale9 stretching work?

Tags: cocos2d-x

In Cocos2d.x 3.0, the ui::Button class has a setScale9Enabled method. But it doesn't seem to work line the old Scale9Sprite in the extensions.

I tried calling setScale9Enabled(true) but I end up with the image divided in 4, but with the corners all in the wrong places. The bottom right corner of the source image in the top left of the rendered image, for example.

I tried calling setCapInsetsNormalRenderer(rect) with various rects (size of image, middle third, etc) but the results were unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set the size of the button.

I tried this image (160x160 pixel):

[image: button.png]

with this code:

```
ui::Button *button = ui::Button::create();
button->setScale9Enabled(true);
button->loadTextureNormal("button.png");
button->setSize(Size(300,160));
button->setTitleText("Button");
button->setPosition(Point(200,200));
addChild(button);
```

and it is working as expected.